# How to focus a field configured inside a fieldGroup of another field in ngx-formly?

Tags: angular-formly

```
export class AppComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({});
  model = {
    investments: [{}, {}],
  };
  options: FormlyFormOptions = {};

  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'investments',
      type: 'repeat',
      fieldArray: {
        fieldGroupClassName: 'row',
        templateOptions: {
          btnText: 'Add another investment',
        },
        fieldGroup: [
          {
            type: 'input',
            key: 'investmentName',
            templateOptions: {
              label: 'Name of Investment:',
              required: true,
            },
          }
        ],
      },
    },
  ];
```

Now 2 input fields will be generated how to focus the second field on some method?
What is the best way to focus a field on some operation in run time?